# CSS not displaying at all in IE but works on Chrome (CodeIgniter used)

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am having difficulties figuring out why Internet Explorer and Firefox would not display the external CSS. Whenever the stylesheet is pasted in the  tag, it displays just fine. Unfortunately, when I include the css external, it doesn't work anymore.

I have tried multiple suggestions but nothing seems to work. When inspecting the page with developer tools, the base_url() function in CodeIgniter returns the correct base URL and hence the correct path to the stylesheet.

Note: Chrome and Safari displays just fine.

Find below a copy of the view in CodeIgniter.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="txt/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "wrapper">
        <?php $this->load->view($header); ?>

        <?php $this->load->view($content); ?>

        <?php $this->load->view($footer); ?>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "text/css" instead of "txt/css". When i fixed this in my Firefox, it worked right away:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev3.acfnola.org/assets/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it and it worked just fine. Something this small almost made me loose my mind.
Is this some new standard?

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be that chrome is more lenient and figured out what you meant with the "txt/css" while Firefox and IE were more strict

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks man. This sure helped a lot. I almost thought something was wrong with CodeIgniter

Comment: Two things to keep in mind: 1. The server may not be serving it up. So go to the url where the css file is. In your case, it was serving the file correctly. 2. If it's not on recognized on your page then it's probably the linking of the file. Which is what your problem was. Also pls accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    

<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/main.css');?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate.